# How to get closest matching value for a given input from DataBase

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql

I am trying to build a SQL query that will fetch me the closest match of the given value, when the user gives an input 8000, I want to fetch one record closest to 8000, one record which is equal to 8000 and one record which is one level higher than 8000. What is the best way to design the data model, SQL to make this operation, I am trying to minimize this with a single query so as to gain the performance, please advice.

Consider this below Example where Employee is table name and name,salary are its attributes

create table employee(name text, salary integer)

This are the sample data of Employee table

```
 Name  | salary
 ----------
 Raju         5000
 Ram          8000
 Sulthan      7000
 Aditya       10,000
```

As i Explained above if i input salary as 8000, I want to fetch one record closest to 8000, one record which is equal to 8000 and one record which is one level higher than 8000

Comment: [edit] your question add the definition of the tables (as `create table` statements), some sample data and the expected output.

Comment: i have edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a window function:

```
select name, salary
from (
  select name, 
         salary,
         case 
            when salary = 8000 then 1 
            when lag(salary) over w = 8000 then 1
            when lead(salary) over w = 8000 then 1
            else 0 
         end as flag
  from employee 
  window w as (order by salary)
) t
where flag = 1;
```

Another option is to use three queries and combine them with a `UNION ALL`

```
select name, salary
from employee 
where salary = 8000
union all
select *
from (
  -- get the highest salary that is lower then 8000
  select name, salary
  from employee 
  where salary < 8000
  order by salary desc
  limit 1
) t
union all
select *
from (
  -- get the smallest salary that is higher then 8000
  select name, salary
  from employee 
  where salary > 8000
  order by salary 
  limit 1
) t
order by salary;
```